# Word meaning the text between opening and closing HTML tags

Tags: html, terminology

In HTML there are tags such as
<div id="abc">TEXT HERE</div>
What would you cal lthe text here part?
I thought about calling it value, but value itself is an attribute of a tag.

Answer (score 6):

Everything from the start tag to the end tag is an "HTML Element"
The bit you refer to is the *element content*

Comment: This is correct, although it also includes nested elements, so might be too general. Having said that, I can't think of anything better.

Comment: Yes - that's a fair point. I can't think of anything more precise either!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it might also be correct to call it CDATA or Character Data, to distinguish it from nested elements (which are markup).

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: Yes but CDATA can also go in the attributes.

Comment: @Matt Ellen Д: Yeah, I wasn't sure if there was a better term to refer to content but not nested elements. I guess not...?

Comment: Eric Meyer, in the chapter on inline elements in "Cascading Style Sheets: The Definitive Guide" calls it "anonymous text". But it is clear that he is using this in the absence of a standard term for it.

Comment: What is it called when you're specifically emphasizing that it's just plain text (i.e., it doesn't have `<em>` or other styling tags)?

Answer (score 1):

It depends, on what *exactly* you are referring to:

- Is it *anything* that's within the `<div>` tag?
- Is it just the *text* within the `<div>` tag?
- Is it just the *first text node* within the `<div>` tag?
- Are you talking about HTML as a language, or about a DOM model of HTML, or about an API accessing the HTML?
- ...

The question is not so easy to answer. Some examples:

- With JavaScript, you can use `innerText` to refer to the text content, whereas you would use `innerHTML` to refer to any HTML content.
- With a DOM library like Dom4j, the generic term for the string within an element is determined by [`getStringValue()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/org/dom4j/Node.java#Node.getStringValue%28%29)
- With XSLT, you can use the `string()` method to retrieve the text
- ...

My personal answer would be to call it the (inner) text of an element.